# Pullback for Atiyah classes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

In his paper "Complex analytic connections in fibre bundles" Atiyah defines his famous Atiyah class $\operatorname{at}(E) \in H^1(X,\operatorname{End}(E) \otimes \Omega^1_X)$ for a vector bundle $E$ on a complex manifold $X$ and he shows that the Chern classes of $E$ can be derived from $\operatorname{at}(E)$. But he also gives a definition for the Atiyah class of an arbitrary coherent sheaf $\mathcal F$ on $X$ which is an element $\operatorname{at}(\mathcal F) \in \operatorname{Ext}_X^1(\mathcal F, \mathcal F \otimes \Omega^1_X )$.

Now, for Chern classes it is well known that they behave functorial with respect to maps $f \colon X \to Y$, i.e.
$$
c_k(f^* E ) = f^* c_k(E)
$$
for any vector bundle $E$ over $Y$. The comparison of the Atiyah-class with Chern classes suggests that such functoriality should also hold for the Atiyah-class of a vector bundle.

But how is it with the Atiyah-class of a coherent sheaf? Say $f \colon X \to Y$ is a map of schemes/analytic spaces and $\mathcal F$ is a coherent sheaf on $Y$.

Question 1: How can we even define the pullback
$$ 
f^* \colon \operatorname{Ext}^1_Y(\mathcal F, \mathcal F \otimes \Omega^1_Y) \to
\operatorname{Ext}^1_X(f^* \mathcal F, f^* \mathcal F \otimes \Omega^1_X)?
$$

Question 2: With an appropriate definition of the above, do we indeed get
$$
\operatorname{at}(f^*\mathcal F) = f^*(\operatorname{at}(\mathcal F ))?
$$

Edit: I see that Question 1 has a straightforward answer in the category of sheaves of Abelian groups. There, the pullback functor $f^{-1}$ is exact. A short exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal F \otimes \Omega^1_Y \to E \to \mathcal F \to 0
$$
is pulled back to a short exact sequence of sheaves of Abelian groups on $X$. Using Yoneda's definition of Ext, we get a notion of pullback. However, in the category of (quasi-)coherent sheaves, the pullback functor
$$
f^* \mathcal F := f^{-1} \mathcal F \otimes_{f^{-1} \mathcal O_Y} \mathcal O_X
$$
is not an exact functor anymore. So what can we do to remedy for that?

Comment: So the issue is that when you pullback the sequence, you get some nonzero Tor sheaves on the left, correct? My immediate thought was "well, longer exact sequences roughly correspond to classes in higher Ext," but of course for that to make any sense you would need $\mathcal F\otimes \Omega_Y^1$ on the far left. But perhaps you need to pass to an invariant that takes values in all Exts, not just $\operatorname{Ext}^1$? A sort of derived Atiyah class whose definition would probably involve a resolution of $\mathcal F$...

Comment: Yes, that is one of the problems: Since $f^*$ is not exact in the category of quasi-coherent sheaves, one is tempted to use the derived pullback instead. However, this does not seem to give anything useful on $X$ that could in any way be interpreted as an Atiyah class. Also, I doubt that taking higher Ext's is useful. By now, I am more convinced that one has to simply work in the category of sheaves of Abelian groups rather than quasi-coherent sheaves. In the end that also seems to be the more natural environment for Chern classes, and hence also the Atiyah class, to live in.